# Generate summary of .NET project

Tags: software-development, .net

Is there a tool that can inspect a .NET project (or maybe a generic code repo) and generate a summary?

This summary could include for example the stack like this:

- .NET 4.5
- MVC 5.2
- EntityFramework 6.2

And maybe some stats about the language used like Open Hub does ([example](https://www.openhub.net/p/openra/analyses/latest/languages_summary#analyses_language_table)).

Just a quick overview of the project instead of a deep analysis like tools as [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

Comment: I was working on the definition of software maintenance services and needed a similar tool, but didn't find one. I finally created my own, based on file extensions (quite simple). Unfortunately I neither work for that company any more nor is the tool available as open source.

Comment: Stats about used languages can be done with onefetch: https://github.com/o2sh/onefetch